# RuntimeError (_app_ctx_err_msg): Working outside of application context while sending mail from thread

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, flask-mail

I am trying to send email using flask-mail and here is the code snippet I have to used to send mail

```
def send_async_email(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)

def send_email(subject, recipients, text_body=None, html_body=None):
    msg = Message(subject, recipients=recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    msg.html = html_body
    thr = Thread(target=send_async_email, args=[current_app, msg])
    thr.start()
```

While running this code, I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread Thread-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "..\flask_demo\flaskdemo\common_utils.py", line 7, in send_async_email
    with app.app_context():
  File "..\flask_demo\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 348, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "..\flask_demo\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 307, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "..\flask_demo\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 51, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

Answer (score 2):

After debugging I have found that the issue is with "current_app", this is a thread local value, when you pass it to __process, we are not passing the actual app object.

This can be solved by using the Proxies, use current_app._get_current_object(). More information at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/#notes-on-proxies

Now, the code looks like this

```
def send_email(subject, recipients, text_body=None, html_body=None):
    msg = Message(subject, recipients=recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    msg.html = html_body
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    thr = Thread(target=send_async_email, args=[app, msg])
    thr.start()
```

Comment: Had the same issue and this solved it. Thank you!